# Use regression or classification when dependent variable is numerical but not continuous

Tags: regression, classification

What algorithm should I use when I have a dependent variable as below:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 17, 21
```

I am trying to build a model where my dependent variable is numerical, but not continuous, and independent variables are combination of factor as well as numerical variables. Please let me know what algorithm should I use to predict dependent variable.

Comment: What do you mean that your dependent variable is "numerical (but not continuous)"? Do you only happen to have those values, or are they the only values possible? Do those values stand for numbers in the regular sense, or are the only codes for unrelated conditions?

Comment: @MaharajanN, if you are the OP, please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.